# How can I check whether an Any value confirms a generic protocol, e.g. IntegerType

Tags: swift

Is it possible to check a value confirms a generic protocol dynamically?

I would like to do something like this:

```
import func Darwin.atoll
func anyToInt(a: Any) -> IntMax {
    if let v = a as? IntegerType { // error!!
        return v.toIntMax()

    } else {
        return atoll("\(a)")
    }
}
```

This makes compile errors with a message "error: protocol 'IntegerType' can only be used as a generic constraint ...".

If I used a correct static type, I would use overloading by type-parameter constraints:

```
func anyToInt<T where T: IntegerType>(a: T) -> IntMax {
    return a.toIntMax()
}
func anyToInt<T>(a: T) -> IntMax {
    return atoll("\(a)")
}
```

Unfortunately, however, there's no method to employ static types instead of Any in my case.

Comment: what happens if u give let v = a as? Int instead of what you have given?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299635/downcast-from-any-to-a-protocol

Comment: There are a lot of types that confirm IntegerType: Int, UInt, Int8, UInt8, Int16, UInt16, and etc. Thus, I want to handle them as a single IntegerType.

Comment: Swift intentionally does not let you treat all integer types interchangeably. Its casting requirement isn't something to work around. Ignoring how the various ranges interact is a historic cause of bugs, and Swift wanted to avoid that. You should build your code to work with `Int` unless you have some specific reason to work with another integer type. See "Numeric Type Conversion" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_467 Working with other integer types should be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t, for a couple of reasons:

Firstly, you [can’t cast the contents of an `Any` to a protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24299635/3925941) that the `Any` might support.  You can only get out the explicit type that’s contained:

```
let i = 1
i as Printable  // works

let a: Any = i
a as? Printable  //  doesn’t work
let p = a as Int as Printable // works
// or, if you don’t want to crash if a isn’t an Int
let p = (a as? Int).map { $0 as Printable } 
// (is there a cleaner syntax than this?)
```

Secondly, you can’t instantiate protocols that have an associated type.  You can only use them as generic constraints.  That example with `Printable` only works because it doesn’t have an associated type.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27726029/3925941) for an explanation of why.  So even if casting `Any` could work on protocols, you couldn’t cast it to an `IntegerType`.

But are you certain you have to use `Any` here?  `Any` really is best avoided unless there’s no alternative.  Maybe you can push generics further up the pipeline?

Comment: Thanks to the answer. In fact, I'd like to use variable-length arguments like `sprintf(format: String, _ args: Any...)` because Swift doesn't support variadic generics :(