# How to compare two `Any` objects those actually conform to `Equatable`

Tags: swift, quick-nimble

I want to implement a `ValueObjectSharedExampleConfiguration: QuickConfiguration` using [`Quick`](https://github.com/Quick/Quick).

```
class ValueObjectSharedExampleConf: QuickConfiguration {
    override class func configure(_ configuration: Configuration) {
        sharedExamples("Value Object") {
            (context: @escaping SharedExampleContext) in
            describe("same objects") {
                it("should be equal") {
                    let obj1a = context()["1a"]
                    let obj1b = context()["1b"]
                    expect(obj1a == obj1b).to(beTrue())
                }
            }
            describe("different objects") {
                it("should not be equal") {
                    let obj1 = context()["1a"]
                    let obj2 = context()["2"]
                    expect(obj1 == obj2).to(beFalse())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I want to test any classes/structs that conforms to `Equatable` with this shared Example like this:

```
itBehavesLike("Value Object") { [ "obj1a": foo1a, "obj1b": foo1b, "obj2": foo2] }
```

But the problem is, `SharedExampleContext` is actually a closure returns `[String: Any]`, so `obj1a`, `obj1b`, `obj2` variables I get in `sharedExample` closure are all of type `Any`, which doesn't necessarily conform to `Equatable`. Thus the code `obj1a == obj1b` won't compile.

Actually if I check `obj1a is Equatable` it returns true. But I don't know how to cast it to a proper type that compiler will accept. `obj1a as! Equatable` won't compile because `Equatable` is a generic protocol.

I can't just write `obj1a as! Foo` because if there is another class `Bar: Equatable` I want my sharedExample also works for that.

The main problem here is: I have two variables cast to `Any`, which are guaranteed to be originally of same type that conforms to `Equatable`. **How should I legally compare these two variables without knowledge of the actual type of them ?**

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299635/downcast-from-any-to-a-protocol

Comment: Shouldn't work since Equatable has Self associated with it

Answer (score 0):

You could have a MyComparable protocol with a function isEqualTo(object: Any) and implement it for Foo and Bar. You can then:

```
let object1 = obj1 as! MyComparable
object1.isEqualTo(obj2)
```

and in the implementation of isEqualTo check the type or force convert it if you are sure it is always the same:

```
class Foo: MyComparable {
    func isEqualTo(_ object: Any) -> Bool {
        let obj2 = object as! Foo
        return self == obj2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an strange solution.

```
func == (lhs: any Equatable, rhs: any Equatable) -> Bool {
    return ([lhs] as NSArray) == ([rhs] as NSArray)
}
```

Here is the code tested with swift 5.7.1

```
protocol GenericItem: Hashable {
    associatedtype Element
    var value: Element { get }
}

struct StringItem: GenericItem {
    var value: String
}

struct IntItem: GenericItem {
    var value: Int
}

// comparison function [A]
func == (lhs: any Equatable, rhs: any Equatable) -> Bool {
    return ([lhs] as NSArray) == ([rhs] as NSArray)
}

let item1: any GenericItem = StringItem(value: "hello")
let item2: any GenericItem = StringItem(value: "hello")
let item3: any GenericItem = StringItem(value: "world")
let item4: any GenericItem = IntItem(value: 24)

// without [A] it causes error as follows
// item1 == item2 // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'any GenericItem' operands
([item1] as NSArray) == ([item2] as NSArray) // true
([item2] as NSArray) == ([item3] as NSArray) // false
item1 == item2 // true
item2 == item3 // false
item3 == item4 // false
```

Since `StringItem` nor `IntItem` are not inherited from `NSObject`, I am not sure how `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` compares two instances of `any Equatable`.  If we know how it works behind the scenes, we may come up with better implementation.

Note: Strange to say, if you change `Hashable` to `Equatable`, it behaves differently.

```
protocol GenericItem: Equatable { // Hashable -> Equatable
    associatedtype Element
    var value: Element { get }
}
// ...snip...
item1 == item2 // false <-- !?
item2 == item3 // false
item3 == item4 // false
```

It may not be a stable behavior. If you like to try, please test you code well before ship your products.